# Square Connect API - Batch API - item image upload

Tags: square-connect

I have a question when using square rest v1 APIs. So I want to use the batch api for uploading images, but the document didn't show how to use batch api [1] for image uploading. If I use the image upload API instead of batch API it works.

So my question is: does current square batch API support image uploading using multi-part content type? If yes, is there any reference available?

[1] https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#post-batch

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the batch api currently does not support uploading item images. There are multiple technical considerations that make it difficult to support at present (for instance, overall request size, network speed, network timeouts, and managing multiple content-type/length negotiations per image).